# attr_accessor, not able to access property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably very stupid question but here we go

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :group_id
end
```

From *irb*

```
# gets record which has group_id set to 106    
foo = Foo.find(1)
foo.group_id
=> nil
```

If I go and remove

> attr_accessor :group_id

All works as it should

```
foo = Foo.find(1)
foo.group_id
=> 106
```

My question is why? Shouldn't attr_accessor create accessor / mutator for property :group_id and that why all should be working. What am I missing?

**Update**

Good answers bellow, just as explanation for my motivation here is I want to use mass assignment of certain properties (you need this since Rails 3.2.x). For that you need attr_accessible , I find that code is much cleaner that way, of course if used responsibly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `group_id` is already a property on your `Foo` object (shown by the fact that it returns 106 when `attr_accessor` is omitted). By adding `attr_accessor` you are overriding what's already there and creating a method reader and writer called `group_id`. The return of the newly defined `group_id` is nil since you don't define anything.

Conceptually, you're ending up with something like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def group_id  # overriding previous definition of 'group_id'
    nil
  end
end
```

---

**Edit:**

If your goal is expose properties then yes, use `attr_accessible`

Comment: That is true, I was under impression that it should be like that. Maybe I should be using attr_accessible for properties that already exist? And attr_accessor for the members I want to expose?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because ActiveRecord automatically maps the attributes in your database table to attributes in the actual model. When you add `attr_accessor` you overshadow the database attribute with you own, newly defined attribute.

Basically, rails automatically defines `attr_accessor` (or something similar) for all attributes in the corresponding database table.

If you're looking for some way on how to make only certain of your attributes accessible for multi-assignment, you should instead look at `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 0):

Without the accessor, for sure you have a `'belongs_to :group'`  in your Foo model, so if you call 'group_id' to an instance of 'Foo' you will get the value of this field.

For instance, if you set an accessor called like that attribute( group_id) it will overwrite the original field and it will return nil, if haven´t assigned any value.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :group_id
end

# gets record which has group_id set to 106    
foo = Foo.find(1)
foo.group_id
=> nil
foo.group_id = "wadus"
=> "wadus"
foo.group_id
=> "wadus"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column by the name group_id in the table, than ActiveRecord defines the accessor for you. When you overwrite it as you did, your calls simply searches for a regular instance variable named group_id, which returns nil.