# Ruby ActiveRecord without Using Rails does not save

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a Pinterest Ruby crawler (not in Rails) where I write the data to a JSON file. 
I created a ActiveRecord for Pins. I also created a a method that loads the data from file to mysql.
But my load_pins method doesn't load any of the data into database, but it does create empty rows for them.
I even put a debugger and tried to manually load some data into my pins table so for example

```
pin = Pin.first
pin.field_id = 1
pin.user_id = 1
pin.save!
```

and it even returned true, and when I do `pin.user_id` it returns 1 but in the database nothing gets saved, or if I just try to print pin it shows empty for everything.

Pin Model:

```
require_relative '../database_configuration'

class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessor :field_id, :user_id, :board_id, :img_url, :is_repin, :is_video, :source, :link, :description, :user_name
  attr_accessible :field_id, :user_id, :board_id, :img_url, :is_repin, :is_video, :source, :link, :description, :user_name

  def to_json
    {
      field_id: field_id,
      user_id: user_id,
      user_name: user_name,
      board_id: board_id,
      img_url: img_url,
      is_repin: is_repin,
      is_video: is_video,
      source: source,
      link: link,
      description: description,
    }
  end
end
```

My Load_pins method

```
def load_pins
  pins = JSON.parse(File.read('pins.json'))
  Pin.create!(pins)
end
```

Mysql

```
mysql> select * from pins;
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------+------+-------------+-----------+
| id | field_id | user_id | board_id | img_url | is_repin | is_video | source | link | description | user_name |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----------+--------+------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |     NULL |    NULL |     NULL | NULL    |        0 |        0 | NULL   | NULL | NULL        | NULL      |
|  2 |     NULL |    NULL |     NULL | NULL    |        0 |        0 | NULL   | NULL | NULL        | NULL      |
```

Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing something when using ActiveRecord outside of Rails?

Comment: Unlikely to be the lack of rails - don't use attr_accessor for database backed attributes - there are many questions relating to this if you want more detail.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's lack of rails, I just mean, since i'm new to using ActiveRecord without rails, I might be missing something.

Comment: and what would be the problem with attr_accessor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [attr\_accessor, not able to access property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521249/attr-accessor-not-able-to-access-property)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521249/attr-accessor-not-able-to-access-property for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove from `attr_accessor` all those that are fields in the `pins` table.

If you add validations, you will see that none of your AR fields are being set, because the `attr_accessor` is overriding the "fields" that AR uses. AR does not look at the values in instance variables defined by the `attr_accessor`, such as `@field_id`.

I say "fields" above, because AR actually stores all the field values in an `attributes` hash.
Then, AR defines methods to read/write from that hash. So, `field_id` is accessible as `attributes[:field_id]` and also as the method `field_id`.