# Rails 4 - nil after creating a valid User - railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm creating a sample_app with railstutorial.org and I have a small problem with creating a new User in Rails 4.
I'm in a chapter 6: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-the_model_file

After creating a new user in Rails console for example:

```
 user = User.new(name: "Example", email: "email@example.com")
```

I got:

```
 #<User id: 2, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2013-12-29 19:53:25", updated_at: "2013-12-29 19:53:25">
```

So that's mean, that I've just created a new user with nil params, but I initialized a name and email....

but when I type:

```
user.name
```

I got:

```
user.name
=> "Example"
```

also in sqlite3 data browser application I see only an empty columns.

My user.rb looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessor :name, :email

     email_regex = /\A[\w.\-]+@[a-z+\d\-.]+\.+[a-z]+\z/i

      validates :name,  :presence   => true,
                :length     => {maximum: 50}
                #:uniqueness => true
      validates :email, :presence   => true,
                :format     => {with: email_regex},
                :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
end
```

So what's wrong? Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You must `save` after `new`, so after `user = User.new(name: "Example", email: "email@example.com")` type `user.save` to save it to the database.

Comment: It doesn't work, it works same with a save like as w/o save.

Comment: I agree with @Vucko. After creating the new user you need to `user.save`. If that still isn't working then maybe try to see if there were any errors. Try `user.errors` and see if there were any errors when saving.

Comment: I saw that, when I modified attr_accessor to attr_writter now it shows a user properly. 
So what is the difference between responding to attr_accesor and attr_writter. I know that attr_accessor = attr_reader + attr_writter, but why one method shows a user and the other not?

Comment: Not a critical answer but may be a helpful one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4701350/2930161
Related:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11521249/2930161
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7081477/2930161

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attr_accessor line altogether, the Rails tutorial doesn't use it, and you don't need it.

Problem solved :)

As for why that doesn't work with accessor but it does with writer, I don't know, but you can definitely do the tutorial for now without getting stuck on that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `attr_accessor` with `attr_accessible`.

`attr_accessor` is used to create setter and getter methods, which is why you are able to retrieve the results from `user.name`.

`attr_accessible` is used to white-list attributes for mass-assignment, essentially allowing you to pass those parameters up through the ORM.

In your case, the creation of these getter and setter methods are overriding the default methods that `ActiveRecord::Base` has already created for you. Use of `attr_accessor` would be for a variable that is not already defined by the columns in your table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :name, :email

     email_regex = /\A[\w.\-]+@[a-z+\d\-.]+\.+[a-z]+\z/i

      validates :name,  :presence   => true,
                :length     => {maximum: 50}
                #:uniqueness => true
      validates :email, :presence   => true,
                :format     => {with: email_regex},
                :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
end
```